# What is the underlying implementation of HttpWebRequest?

Tags: c#

I am assuming [WinInet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385438%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but I would like to know for sure. Does BITS use the same implementation?

Comment: What is BITS? (Sorry - not an acronym I immediately recognise)

Comment: Background Intelligent Transfer Service. It's a Windows component.  See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa362708%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks - it looks like BITS works at a higher level - it uses things like HTTP to transport the data?

Comment: Yea, no idea what BITS uses.  I think it uses its own thing.  This doc seems to indicate it's separate from WinInet (see page 15): http://www.docstoc.com/docs/26270187/Background-Intelligent-Transfer-Service

Comment: @Peter Any reason you need to know the underlying implementation?

Comment: @rsbarro I am using BITS but it may be limited in ways I hadn't thought of - proxy problems, admin privileges, can be disabled (by user, virus) - so I was wondering if I should write my own transfer mechanism that replicates BITS functionality and I wanted to know the underlying mechanism of HttpWebRequest.

Comment: @Peter If BITS does everything you need then it might be tough to make a case for rolling your own without first checking to see if the stuff that you mentioned is actually a problem (I imagine it would handle proxies at least). If you do roll your own, it appears that HttpWebRequest does handle proxies properly by default (it will use what is specified in IE), according to the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.proxy.aspx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not 100 percent sure what you are asking, but from the Rotor Shared Source I would guess that HttpWebRequest is implemented in C# on top of the sockets implementation - e.g. see http://www.koders.com/csharp/fid437F928E66BF52175A1D00E18452844B1590647F.aspx?s=httpwebrequest.cs#L2 - it certainly doesn't look like Rotor uses PInvoke to WinInet.

Comment: Yep, I looked using ILSpy and I don't see any Win32 references for HttpWebRequest or WebRequest in there. Looks like completely managed code, no? Is there a better way to check?